# How to compare two geotiff datasets

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I have two geotiff with the same projection and the same dimension. One dataset is related to population and the other one to distances. I want to count the population only in the pixels where the distance is greater than `10`. This is what I am doing:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

d = 10
data1 = src.open('population.tif').read(1)
data2 = src.open('distance.tif').read(1)
population = np.sum(data1[np.where(data2>d) ])
```

Is there a way to do the same without working with the arrays but directly with `rasterio` or `gdal`?

Comment: Since your datasets have the same projection and the same dimensions, working with the arrays using boolean indexing is surely the best way. Not sure why you would try to look for another way? In any case, both `rasterio` and `gdal` return an array on read. There are tools like `gdal_calc` but in my experience that's always less performant for these easy tasks

Comment: @Val because I have vary huge rasters (~`30GB`) and it takes a very long time to load the as arrays.